# Calculus of Variations-First and Second Order Deviations

Tags: self-learning, calculus-of-variations

I'm new to Calculus of Variations and the Method of Least Action (L=T-V)
What I'm unsure about is how first and second order deviations are used in finding the least action.

I know it's used to find a minimum but I'm not sure how.

Comment: First variation functional must be zero; second variation must be positive (semi-)definite. But frankly, your question looks more like a request for a lecture on calculus of variations than a specific question.

Comment: Sorry. But, your answer was very helpful.